# White screen of death when accessing Accessories in CP

Tags: add-on, control-panel, white-screen-of-death

I have been having this issue with multiple EE installs since about 2.5.5.

Everytime I try to go to Accessories in the CP, I get a white screen with no errors. I tried turning debugging on in my index.php but get no errors output. Any ideas?

I have nothing except safecracker on my site right now, I uninstalled and deleted everything else that wasn't default (add-ons/extensions/etc) to see if that would help also. My cache folder & contents are set to 777 permissions, my accessories folder is 755 (haven't changed that). I have no idea why I can't access the page.

Comment: Is this just on the Addons > Accessories page and no-where else?

Comment: Also, is this a clean install of 2.5.5 or an upgrade?

Comment: Yes it's only that page, and it was a clean install each time this happened. I think it is attached to some sort of issue with the devot:ee monitor add-on cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm moving the question poster's comment here as an answer:

"... I can access the accessories page now. I believe it was a problem attached to the Devot:ee monitor add-on. I removed the cache for it and reinstalled it and was able to access the page again."

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried disabling all extensions via the config file?

**/system/expressionengine/config/config.php**

```
$config['allow_extensions'] = 'n';
```

That will temporarily stop the extensions from loading but it doesn't remove them.

If you look in the database at the table `exp_accessories` what is listed in there? Try deleting any rows in there except the default EE Info, reload and try again. (If you do have any extensions that you wish to keep just make a note of them and install them again afterwards).

Reload and try again. Still a white screen of death?

Comment: I am unsure what happened...but I can access the accessories page now. I believe it was a problem attached to the Devot:ee monitor add-on. I removed the cache for it and reinstalled it and was able to access the page again.